# Which Index is best for PostgreSQL inet datatype?

Tags: database, postgresql, ip

I am using PostgreSQL to get "IP to City" data from the table, but it is taking too much time to respond. I am also using **btree** indexing on **network** column.

My Query is :

> **SELECT** city_name, subdivision, country_name, continent_name **FROM** ip4_to_city_tbl **WHERE** '104.225.250.92' <<= network **LIMIT** 1;

Table 'ip4_to_city_tbl' is have **9685491** records.

If we have more than 400 requests in 1 second, then it takes 200 to 900 milliseconds to respond.

I want the response of query within 10 milliseconds.

EXPLAIN command shows **Seq Scan**  on ip4_to_city_tbl query instead of Index Scan

So please tell me, what should do to improve response time and Which Index is best for PostgreSQL inet datatype?

Answer (score 8):

In general, inet_ops index types are preferred for inet and cidr data types.

```
 create index on ip4_to_city_tbl using gist (network inet_ops);
```

Comment: It is showing `ERROR:  operator class "inet_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"`

Comment: Now it is working perfectly after Updating PostgreSQL Version to 10.4
**Thanks @Joe Love**